# OpenNI 2 and Groovy

Tags: openni, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I am currently using ROS Groovy with my robot. I was using OpenNI and NITE 1.5 but I had some bugs so I would like to change to OpenNI 2.

I found the drivers openni2_camera on Groovy. But I was also using openni_tracker with Groovy, and the new version openni2_tracker is only available for Hydro. Does someone know what I can do ? Is the Hydro version compatible with Groovy ?

Same thing for using the Kinect, I saw that openni2_camera is not working for Kinect, so I will try with freenect_stack, but will openni2_tracker work with Kinect and freenect_stack ?

Thanks for information,

Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88526/openni-2-and-groovy/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to successfully get `openni2_camera` and `openni2_tracker` compiled and working for both Groovy and Fuerte.  But when I actually tried to run the tracker, I kept getting errors.  Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_tracker/blob/hydro-devel/src/openni2_tracker.cpp) for the tracker, it became clear that the port to OpenNI2 wasn't quite complete yet.  Since I last tried it, there have been a few commits, but it still doesn't quite look done (to me).  I'm sure they wouldn't mind a pull request if you had time to help finish it off.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-10-08**:
Thanks for the answer. When I try to compile openni2_tracker, it's looking for an include file nite.h and I get an error message. So I tried to download Nite 2.0 and install it but it doesn't change anything. Do you know what I need to get this include file ?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-10-08**:
Ok I just found the solution to get it compile. I just needed to take the environment variable created by Nite and export them. I will test the tracker and say if it's working or not. Thanks again.

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-10-08**:
I managed to test the user_tracker and it works. At the beginning I had problems because I was not in the right directory. To make it run I needed to be in the 'Redist' directory of Nite2.0 and also you don't need to run openni2.launch as I was used to do with last version of openni. Hope this can help you.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-10-09**:
Those are basically the same steps I had to take to get things running on my computer as well.  Sorry for not posting a more complete solution! I haven't tried running running the tracker in a few weeks, maybe it's time to try again.  Cheers!